# Removing actionBar crashes my app (It says Unfortunately, app has stopped)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

I'm new to app dev and have searched for a solution to this problem to no avail. I'm creating an app for that incorporates webview and I'm trying to remove the action bar I've tried using `actionBar.hide();` and `actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`. I even tried `actionBar.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled(true);`. What it does is open the app window, then the screen goes black, the app closes and [Unfortunately, app has stopped] pops up.

here's my code
    `

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    WebView webA;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webA.canGoBack()) {
            webA.goBack();
        }
    else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);//hide title


    webA = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webA);
    webA.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // This ensures that it's opened in the webView not default browser
    webA.loadUrl("https://www.fiander.me");

    // Progress bar
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    // WebView
    WebSettings webSettings = webA.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webA.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
```

`

Comment: I found a way to fix it. What I did was:

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest `AndroidManifest.xml` you define your app's theme, something like:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and this theme is defined in `styles.xml`,  something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.LightActionBar">
```

change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

so there is no `ActionBar` in your app 
and you can remove this code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);//hide title
```

from `onCreate()`

Comment: I tried it from manifest. It didn't work. It finally worked when i changed it from the style.xml

Comment: @OrangeUncle my answer says change the styles.xml not the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it. What I did was:

In the projects tab I went into -- res > values > styles.xml.

then changed the parent name to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
like so:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```